# How can I tweak this algorithm to deal with multiple occurrences of a keyword to modify?

Tags: c, algorithm, file, file-io, replace

I would like to search for all occurrences of a string (first parameter) and have another string (second parameter) be added before all occurrences of the first string.

Ideally, I would like every occurrence of `dime` to be replaced with `limedime`.
I have managed to do this, however, for only the first occurrence of the word.
Any matching string which is not the first is not detected, and nothing is done. Also, multiple lines containing `dime` get modified based on modifications done on previous lines, which is not what I would like.

Here is some sample output that I get:

```
something dime something dime something something
```

will become

```
something limedime something dime something something
```

and if I have this

```
dime
notimportant!
dime
dime
```

I will get

```
limedime
notimportant!
limelimedime
limelimelimedime
```

EDIT: I've modified the code so you can easily test it with `stdin`, and have also included `replace_str()`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
  static char buffer[4096];
  char *p;

  if(!(p = strstr(str, orig)))  
    return str;

  strncpy(buffer, str, p-str); 
  buffer[p-str] = '\0';

  sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));

  return buffer;
}

void replace(char* patternoo, char* replacearoo){

    char buff[BUFSIZ];      // the input line
    char newbuff[BUFSIZ];   // the results of any editing

    char pattern[200];
    strcpy(pattern, patternoo);

    char replace[200];
    strcpy(replace, replacearoo);

    while ( fgets( buff, BUFSIZ, stdin ) != NULL ) {
        if ( strstr( buff, pattern ) != NULL ) {
             //THIS IS WHERE WE DO pattern replacing    
                strcpy(newbuff, replace_str(buff, pattern, strcat(replace,pattern)));             

        } else {
              strcpy( newbuff, buff );
        }
          printf("%s", newbuff);
    }
}
int main(){

    replace("dime", "lime");
}
```

Now, I'm thinking that maybe this way isn't too great, since I'm only looking at lines? I'm not sure what I can do, read every character one by one? It seems a bit much to me, but I am not so sure. Is there any quick and dirty way to fix my current algorithm though? Or would I have to start over and take a whole new approach?

Comment: (a) You need a loop instead of an `if` around your `strstr()` call — that's why you only get one substitution per line.  (b) Since your string grows, you have to be careful about how you handle the destination (it can't be done in place).  Your code is more complex than an MCVE ([MCVE]) because it is opening files — for an MCVE, it would be better (simpler, hence more minimal) to read from standard input and write to standard output only.  The file handling is a separate part of the exercise, readily fixable once you've got the basics working.  It's probably worth writing more functions.

Comment: The *"limelimelimedime"* problem is due to the `strcat(replace,pattern)` inside the `while` loop. The solution is impossible to know since all of the problems you describe come from the call to `replace_str`, and you haven't shown the code for `replace_str`. Which is to say that I agree with JonathanLeffler that you need to post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, I have edited the question and the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Edited the question. Also, I am not too sure how I can implement a loop in here. The else statement down there is essential, and my shoddy attempts at implementing a while loop got me a few segfaults.

Comment: I admire your confidence in writing the line `strcpy(newbuff, replace_str(buff, pattern, strcat(replace,pattern)));` — I certainly can't work out what that _is_ doing; I'm not even sure (yet) what it is supposed to be doing.  Let's put it like this; I think that what you're doing here is more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you insert `lime` before each occurrence of `dime`, you need to read a line, find each occurrence of `dime` in the input buffer, and when found, copy the unprocessed part of the input buffer to the output buffer, then add `lime`, then add `dime`, and then resume your search after the `dime`.

That translates to:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void replace(char *pattern, char *replace)
{
    char buff[BUFSIZ];      // the input line
    char newbuff[BUFSIZ];   // the results of any editing
    size_t replen = strlen(replace);
    size_t patlen = strlen(pattern);

    while (fgets(buff, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        newbuff[0] = '\0';
        char *dst = newbuff;
        char *data = buff;
        char *patt;
        while ((patt = strstr(data, pattern)) != NULL)
        {
            memmove(dst, data, (patt - data));
            dst += (patt - data);
            memmove(dst, replace, replen);
            dst += replen;
            memmove(dst, pattern, patlen);
            dst += patlen;
            data = patt + patlen;
        }
        *dst = '\0';
        printf("%s%s", newbuff, data);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    replace("dime", "lime");
    return 0;
}
```

The code blithely ignores the existence of over-long expansions of input lines — you need to work to make sure that it does not overflow the output buffer.  Since you insert 4 characters (`lime`) for each `dime` (4 characters), at worst you need twice as much space in the output as there is in the input.  So, changing the size of `newbuff[2 * BUFSIZ]` would deal with those overflow problems — for the specific strings you're prefixing.  Overlong input lines could cause misses too.  If a `dime` was split across the boundary between two buffers full, it would be missed.

Given a file called `data` (concocted from your question):

```
something dime something dime something something

    should become

something limedime something limedime something something

    and if I have this

dime
not important!
dime
dime dime
dime dime dime

    I will get limes and dimes galore:

limedime
not important!
limedime
limedime limedime
limedime limedime limedime
```

The output from running the program (`repstr`, I called it) is:

```
$ ./repstr < data
something limedime something limedime something something

    should become

something limelimedime something limelimedime something something

    and if I have this

limedime
not important!
limedime
limedime limedime
limedime limedime limedime

    I will get limes and limedimes galore:

limelimedime
not important!
limelimedime
limelimedime limelimedime
limelimedime limelimedime limelimedime
$
```

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't see past what I had, and this looks to be a much more elegant way to go about things.

Answer (score 1):

one approach may be:

```
Have a temp string that displays output.

Until whole sentence read
   Read complete word of that sentence.
   if that word == dime
      append limedime to temp string
   else append the same word to temp string.
```

Dryrun:

```
input: something dime somthing lime dime

iteration1: something read compare it with lime, they arent equal so append somthing to temp string.
temp: something

iteration2: word read: dime
temp: something limedime

iteration3: word read: something
temp: something limedime something

and soo on.
```

Hope this approach helps :)
Haven't touched C for ages so i forgot its syntax so can't help with coding pseudo should suffice tho.