# Implementation of findAndReplace function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, recursion

I need to write my own implementation of a function which finds a string (word1) in another string (text) and replaces all instances of word1 in text with a third string (word2).
This is what I have thus far;

```
void findandreplace(char text[],const char word1[], const char word2[])
{
    char *start;
    char *end;
    start=strstr(text,word1);
    end=start;
    if (strcmp(text,start))
    {
        end+=strlen(word2);
        strcpy(&text[end-start+1],&text[(int)start]);
        strcpy(text,word2);
        findandreplace(end,word1,word2);
    }
    if (!strcmp(text,start))
    {
        end++;
        findandreplace(end,word1,word2);
    }
    if (!text)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I have made plenty of mistakes in writing this, but please keep in mind I am essentially a complete noob. Any help pointing out mistakes and possible corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd start fixing your indentation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code *and* accurately describe the problem.  As far as we can see, you haven't tried to run your code, and thus have not yet encountered any actual problem for us to solve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35476087/971127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works properly. Note, that it assumes `word1` and `word2` to be of equal length, therefore it is merely an idea of how could it be done, not final solution.

```
void findandreplace(char text[], const char word1[], const char word2[])  
{
    if(strlen(word1) == strlen(word2) &&   
        strcmp(word1, word2)) // The same lengths and words aren't equal to each other.
    {
        char *start;
        // start=strstr(text, "good"); // We don't seek string "good",
        start = strstr(text, word1);  // but string word1[].
        while(start != NULL)
        {
            strncpy(start, word2, strlen(word2));
            start = strstr(text, word1);
        }
    }
}
```

Referring to your code:

- `start` points to substring "good" (if exists), but you want to search for `word1[]`.
- `text[(int)start]` - casting pointer to int makes no sense. If you want to obtain index in `text[]` to which `start` points, you need to use pointer arithmetic: `text[start - text]`.
- `strcpy(text, word2)` will make `text[]` an actual copy of `word2` string, what you need is `strncpy(..)`